# Get Value from One Table based on a Value in another table in Pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, join, merge

I have the two tables below: One table is Orders and the other table is a Master table. Both are dataframes in Pandas, Python.

```
Orders
-------------
Date  | item_id
--------------
672022| 123
672022| 976
672022| 532
--------------

Master Table
----------------------------------------------
item_id | Description | Supplier | Ship_From
----------------------------------------------
234     | Oranges     | CWF      | NY
341     | Nuts        | DVR      | NJ
532     | Grapes      | ETT      | CT
123     | Apples      | ERH      | CT
976     | Raspberry   | HKQ      | NY
731     | Bread       | FBE      | NJ
-----------------------------------------------
```

I want my final table to look like the below:

```
-------------------------------
Date  | item_id | Description
-------------------------------
672022| 123     | Apples
672022| 976     | Raspberry 
672022| 532     | Grapes
-------------------------------
```

I am unable to get the desired output in a simple way What is the best way to write joins code in Python?
I am using the below code:

```
new = pd.merge(orders, master, on="item_id", how="left")
new = new[['Date', 'item_id', 'description']]
new.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=True)
```

Comment: I am getting many rows when I do a right or left join because my master table is huge. I need a simple table with item_id and description

Comment: I get exactly the result you want with exactly your code. I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data1 = '''Date  | item_id
--------------
672022| 123
672022| 976
672022| 532'''

data2 = '''item_id | Description | Supplier | Ship_From
234     | Oranges     | CWF      | NY
341     | Nuts        | DVR      | NJ
532     | Grapes      | ETT      | CT
123     | Apples      | ERH      | CT
976     | Raspberry   | HKQ      | NY
731     | Bread       | FBE      | NJ'''

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data1), sep='\s*\|\s*', engine='python')
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data2), sep='\s*\|\s*', engine='python')
df1.merge(df2[['item_id', 'Description']], on='item_id', how='inner')
```

output:

|  | Date | item_id | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 672022 | 123 | Apples |
| 1 | 672022 | 976 | Raspberry |
| 2 | 672022 | 532 | Grapes |